# make noise on redhat when command is finished

Tags: unix, redhat

i am developing some software with a significant build time, so i want to execute the build command and play a noise once it is finished.  two questions:

1. how do i make some noise from the command line (Redhat Enterprise Linux 5)?
2. i am doing the build on a remote machine, so is there something like X11 forwarding for sound that will play the noise on my machine?

if #2 isn't possible/easy i guess i could just execute the build command on the remote machine and play the noise locally.  thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can echo the `BEL` character, perhaps multiple times, from your build script.

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "\a\a\a"
```

The above example will print the `BEL` character 3 times.  Thus, the PC speaker should emit 3 beeps.

Comment: Note that if you're using Bash instead of `sh` you'll need `echo -en "\a\a\a" (the `-n` suppresses the newline). Also, in either case I only get one "ding". You can loop with a short `sleep` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

What about printing the BEL character (0x07)?
It should make a ping!/beep! on the terminal.